# What does the Heaviside function $\theta(-x-vt)$ look like?

Tags: functions

I know what the Heaviside function looks like when it is simply $\theta(x)$, but I'm not sure how to interpret $\theta(-x-vt)$ where $v,t>0$ and $v$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In half the $(x,t)$ plane - when $x+vt>0$ - it is zero; in the other half-plane, it is 1.

Comment: Presumably $\nu$ is a velocity for you, in which case $\theta(-x -\nu t)$ is a wavefront traveling at speed $\nu$.

Comment: @Michael What happened to the negative?

Comment: When $-x-vt>0$, it is 1; when $-x-vw<0$, it is zero.  But I prefer David's answer to mine.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In the problem I am working on, I believe $v$ is just a constant. However, if it were the velocity how would it become a wavefront?

Comment: @Michael is it $\dfrac{1}{2}$ at $x=0$?

Comment: I suppose so.  At time $t_1$, the step down is at $x=-vt_1$; at time $t_2$, the step is at $x=-vt_2$.  So there is a retreat of water, height 1, traveling to the left.